# I need to edit or remove an Inline style

Tags: jquery, inline-styles

A jQuery plugin is applying an inline style overriding my CSS style (left:147). I want to change this to center my h1

What's the best way to edit this style or remove this inline style completely?

I have tried everything I could to no avail

Comment: add !important to the rule in css?

Comment: whatt plugin is doing this

Comment: Please show what you have tried that isn't working. There are solutions for this all over the web and this site. We can't guess what you have done and shouldn't need to re-invent the wheel for it either. Also provide a [mcve]

Comment: @raviolican themepunch slider revolution